# I am creating a game but the score wont update more than once in this simple code. it updates to 10 once and stays the same after that no matter what

Tags: python

This is the code -

```
import random
def game():
    randno = random.randint(1,11)
    a = int(input("guess a number from 1 to 10 - "))
    if randno == a:
        for d in range(0, 1000001):
            d+=10
            print ("gud, score increased by 10")
            return d
    else :
        return (0)

with open("hiscore.txt", "r") as a:
    S = a.read(int())

HS = game()
if S=="":
    with open("hiscore.txt", "w") as b:
        b.write(str(HS))
elif HS>S:
    with open("hiscore.txt", "w") as b:
        b.write(str(HS))
```

The score should be increased by 10 every time u guess the correct  number, the score will increase by 10 and should appear in another file called hiscore.txt. the issue is that the score does get increased but  only once. this means that it only increases  the score to 10 the first time and does not increase after that no matter how many time you guess correct

Comment: It does get increased. The problem here is that `return` only returns once.

Comment: Remove the `return d` and I belive you are good to go.

Comment: Why do you have a loop around `d += 10`? That's the same as increasing `d` by `10 * 1000001`

Comment: @Jackson If they do that, how will they return the score to the caller?

Comment: What is the `for` loop supposed to be for? Is the user supposed to guess a million and 1 random numbers?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you want:

```
def game():
    d = 0
    for _ in range(0, 1000001):
        randno = random.randint(1,11)
        a = int(input("guess a number from 1 to 10 - "))
        if randno == a:
            d += 10
            print ("gud, score increased by 10")
    return d
```

Move the no loop outside, and skip the else part. Also `return` outside the loop.

Comment: The user is going to get very bored if they have to guess a million numbers.

Comment: @U12-forward i tried ur answer but it did not work

Comment: the same thing happened